# CSS rectangle button on it and text inside it

Tags: css

I need to create this type of shape, the green part is a button.
This design is for smartphone only and the rectangle must cover whole width of screen.

[image]

Comment: so us what have you tried so far..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this one. Hope it helps you.

Note: Just change the element of button if you are using anchor tag instead.

```css
.placeholder-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.placeholder-box p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.placeholder-box ul {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Button */

button {
 display: block;
 border: solid white;
 border-width: 0 10px;
 border-radius: 0;
 background: green;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin: -60px auto 15px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="placeholder-box">
  <button type="button"> Button Text Here </button>
  <p>Nunc condimentum mauris elit</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Duis quis eros felis</li>
    <li>Nulla facilisi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you , i hv find this code for long time to use in my new project

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div style="padding:100px;" align="center">
    <a style=" background-color:#01B901;background-color: #01B901;padding: 50px;color: white;padding-top: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;">hello btn</a>
    </div>
```

is this what u wan?

Comment: Thanks, but the main thing i am concerned is the border which is surrounding the button and the text, which yous have not mentioned here